# Prevent a tree node from being moved to its children, grand children nodes with recursion

Tags: java

I'm new to recursion. I need to prevent a tree node got moved to its children, grand-children.. nodes. The issue I met is I can prevent a tree node from being moved to its children. However, when it got moved to its grand-children node, the branch disappeared. The expected result is do nothing.

```
    private void movePosition(Position pos, Position target) {
        if (pos == null || target == null) {return;} 
        if (!inSubtree(pos, target)) {
            UI.println("safe to move ");
            pos.getManager().removeFromTeam(pos);
            target.addToTeam(pos);
        }
        else {UI.println("cannot move parent to children ");}
    }

    private boolean inSubtree(Position pos, Position subtree) {. // <--- Has to use recursion
        if (subtree.getManager() == pos) return true;
        for (Position subtreeTeam: subtree.getTeam()) {
            if (pos==subtree) return true;
            inSubtree(pos, subtreeTeam);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I'm sure English is a barrier here, but the wording of your question is hard to understand. Maybe rephrase to make clearer.  That said, you can immediately conclude that something is broken about `inSubtree` because it returns an important value, but the recursive call ignores it.  What you actually want is the logical "or" of all tests of whether subtrees contains the target. In fact if you ever see a `true` return, you can stop checking subtrees and return true.

Comment: You're gonna need to provide some examples because your question is almost impossible to understand. Start with sample input, expected output, and show code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all of your children/grandchildren/etc at once, and then check if the pos is this Collection. Try creating a getter in Position that do this for you, using Stream.